# Split String after first slash using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, split, strsplit

I have multiple string where i want to split my string after first slash if it matches to specific pattern. But I am not finding way for it. I am using postgresql.

```
Split_column
PA067
PA089/GHC
PA001/FDCJ/988S
```

After PA---, there xan be 0 to n slashes.
Now I am using,

```
case when  split_column ilike '%PA%' then split_part(split_column, '/', 2)
```

But here I need all, irrespective of position like
For PA001/FDCJ/988S --> FDCJ/988S

Answer (score 1):

Would `position` work?

```
substring (split_column , position ('/' in split_column ) + 1)
```

This just says take the string immediately after the first occurrence of '/'.